# Content instead Excerpt on term

Tags: search, terms, content, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to show limitation (dynamically) of the contents near the search term value. I knew how how to using excerpt, but what I am talking about is, search result content limitation character only near the search term value.

Thanks,
Zee

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to limit the actual showing of the search query ( the keywords that the users searches ) on the search page. Or do you want to limit the content that the search results pull?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My planning, I am used highlight text based on search terms. Currently, I am using excerpt but some of the highlighted not appear on search result because I am limiting the character using excerpt (e.g. excerpt 20 chars, the search results founded by wp, but the terms in the next 20 chars in contents that why not showing up). is more dynamically excerpt near the terms result

Comment: You want to find the search terms in the post content and display the text surrounding those terms?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to show it. but got stack

Comment: Mmmm...guess no one can help me. Let me trying to summarize:show an excerpt of the place in the feature where the search result/hit is?